# Triggering a multibranch pipeline job from github enterprise webhook

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am attempting to trigger multi-branch pipeline jobs from a GitHub enterprise server. I have the webhook configured to send a notification on all events. The event log on github enterprise shows that the requests to Jenkins are successful, however on the multibranch pipeline the event log is empty.

My multibranch pipeline jobs are being created using JobDSL like so:

```html
    multibranchPipelineJob("build_${repo}") {
        branchSources {
            branchSource {
                source {
                    git {
                      id("${org}.${repo}")
                      remote("git@${githubEntrerpise}:${org}/${repo}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        configure {
            def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
            traits << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {}
        }
        triggers {
            periodic(1) // Trigger every min.
        }
        orphanedItemStrategy { discardOldItems { numToKeep(10) } }
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by changing the webhook endpoint I was using.
Changing it to the following format solved the issue `http://[JENINS_HOST]/git/notifyCommit?url=git@[GIT_REPO].git`